# Wrong encoding in xml response on PowerShell Invoke-WebRequest

Tags: powershell-3.0

I'm using Invoke-WebRequest to retreive an xml document. In the xml declaration encoding="UTF-8" is specified. When I view the document in a browser it looks correct. But when I retreive it in PowerShell and save some content from it to a DB or print it to the console the encoding gets wrong and "Joe's" becomes "Joeâs".

The XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <element attribute="Joe's"></element>
</root>
```

The script:

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://example.com/doc.xml"
$xml = [xml]$response.Content
$xml.root.element.attribute
```

The output:

```
Joeâs
```

Shouldn't this just work?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this might not be an encoding issue. I tried converting using 139 different encodings and in none of the output files was scandinavian characters inside the XML correct. I used this code:

```
$outPath = "C:\Temp\"; 
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $headers -Body ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($body)) -Uri $url -Method Post;
encodings = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncodings();

foreach($item in $encodings) {
    $original = $result.OuterXml;

    $defaultEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding($item.name);
    $utf8Bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTf8.GetBytes($original)
    $decoded = $defaultEncoding.GetString($utf8Bytes);

    $Utf8NoBomEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding $False;
    [System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines(($outPath +$item.Name + ".xml"), $decoded , $Utf8NoBomEncoding)
}
```

When i call on the same REST Api using curl in Windows I have no problems with the encoding, the result i get back is in UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue using the `[xml]` parsing. I worked it around by doing the parsing myself:

```
$xml = New-Object xml
$resolver = New-Object -TypeName System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver
$resolver.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultCredentials
$reader = New-Object -TypeName System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings
$reader.XmlResolver = $resolver
$reader = [System.Xml.XmlReader]::Create($rssUrl, $reader)
$xml.Load($reader)
```